# extract some email

Tags: php, regex

I have something like this :

```
test<test@test.com>, test1<test1@test.com>,test2<test2@test.com>
```

I try to extact only the email  : `test@test.com`

my function

```
      public static function extractEmail($string)
{
  $emails = [];

  foreach (preg_split('/\s/', $string) as $token) {
    $email = filter_var(filter_var($token, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL), FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
    if ($email !== false) {
      $emails[] = $email;
    }
  }

  return $emails;
}
```

Result `$email` : I have `testtest@test.com` and not

```
test@test.com
```

Than you

Comment: `/(?<=<)[a-z]+[@].*?(?=>)/`

Answer (score 0):

You can create,call and use the following function.

```
<?php
    function stripText($text){
        $lesspos=stripos($text,"<")+1;//finding the position of < and set the start of substring by adding one
        $greatpos=stripos($text,">")+1;//finding the position of >
        $length=strlen($text)-$lesspos-$greatpos;//length of the string between the two symbol
        $stripedtext=substr($text,$lesspos,$length);//striping the text we need out
        return $stripedtext;//returning the striped text
    }
    $text="test<test@example.com>";
    echo stripText($text);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

To match the email addresses for the example string, you could use a capturing group and the `\G` anchor to get continuous matches after matching the first part of the string.

```
(?:[^\s<>]+<|\G(?!^))([^\s@<>]+@[^\s@<>]+)>(?:,\h*|$)
```

**Explanation**

- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `[^\s<>,]+<` Match 1+ times any char other than a whitespace char or brackets
  - `|` Or
  - `\G(?!^)` Assert the position at the end of the previous match
- `)` Close group
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[^\s@<>]+@[^\s@<>]+` Match an email like pattern using a negated character class
- `)` Close group 1
- `>(?:,\h*|$)` Match `>` and either a comma and 0+ horizontal whitespace chars or assert the end of the string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/b6X0Jl/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/1DVni)

For example

```
$re = '/(?:[^\s<>]+<|\G(?!^))([^\s@<>]+@[^\s@<>]+)>(?:,\h*|$)/';
$str = 'test<test@test.com>, test1<test1@test.com>,test2<test2@test.com>';
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => test@test.com
    [1] => test1@test.com
    [2] => test2@test.com
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can this help you :

```
$pattern = '/(?<=<)(.*?)+(?=\>)/';
$string = 'test<test@test.com>, test1<test1@test.com>,test2<test2@test.com>';
preg_match_all($pattern , $string , $emails);
var_dump($emails[0]);
```

Result:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(13) "test@test.com"
  [1]=>
  string(14) "test1@test.com"
  [2]=>
  string(14) "test2@test.com"
}
```